# How to remove parent themes function file filter in child themes function file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to remove parent themes function file filter in child themes function file.

**function file**

```
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {                                            

    return $output. ' prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"';
}
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');
```

And I have try to remove child theme like as

```
remove_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: remove filter using priority , may be using early priority will  help you remove the filter.

Answer (score 4):

A child theme's `functions.php` file will run before the parent, so it will not be registered yet.

You could wait for the `init` action to remove the filter.

```
function remove_language_attributes() {                                            
    remove_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');
}
add_filter('init', 'remove_language_attributes');
```

Comment: Hi @jay! Glad I could help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, and also note that there may be a delay before you are able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can set priority in your filter like this :

```
 add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype', 10);
```

and set child them filter priority to grater than 10.